# Remove subarray from array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know it might be a stupid question, but I didn't find any solution for it.
For example, if I have the `arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]]` and I want to remove the subarray `[1,2,2]`. Is it possible in Javascript?

The result should be: `[[1,2,3],[4,3]]`. Also, if I try to remove `[0,1,2]`, nothing happens because the arr1 does not have the subarray `[0,1,2]`

Comment: How are you wanting to identify the sub-array to remove? Sounds like you might want a combination of [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript) and [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: That's in may problem. I don't know how to identify the subArray.

Comment: Using the links above, you should be able to work it out. If you're still having trouble, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62629289/edit) to show what you tried and we should be able to help from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove arrays of the same length which have the exact same elements:

```js
function removeSubArray(source, sub) {
  let i = source.length;
  while(i--) {
    if (source[i].length === sub.length && sub.every((n, j) => n === source[i][j])) {
      source.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const arr2 = [1,2,2];

removeSubArray(arr1, arr2);

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: I like that this removes **all** the matching arrays, not just the first.

Comment: It's awesome. Thank you. Could you please explain the while(i--)? What's the condition to stop the loop?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 I'm doing `i--` because I'm going backwards, from right to left. This is practical, because when splicing, we are removing elements, so we would have to use some hacks to keep `i` consistent when going from left to right. As for the stop, that will happen when `i` is equal to `0`, because `0` is a falsy value. `i--` returns the current value of `i`, and then subtracts `1` from it